# Implementing QoS on a gateway box that runs Fedora

Tags: iptables, fedora, qos

I configured a small factor PC to run as my gateway/file server/backup server/etc for my apartment. I want to implement QoS based on source IP address to prevent my roommates from bogging down my connection. What would be the best way to go about it?

I already use iptable for my NAT routing and my firewall. Seems like the *mangle* table is exactly what I'm looking for but--from what I've read--it's not that simple.

Some tips and/or articles would certainly help. I'm ready to dedicate some time into this after I was force disconnected from my Starcraft 2 game because of lag caused by my roommates watching Netflix HD and Hulu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tc(traffic control), for more information read this questions: [How can I do traffic shaping in Linux by IP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/191560/how-can-i-do-traffic-shaping-in-linux-by-ip).

tldp: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html
lartc: http://lartc.org/