# How can I limit server bandwidth per IP

Tags: apache-2.2, bandwidth-control

I would like to limit the download speed of my .mkv and my .mp4 files 
My page have got 1000-3000 visitor per day

I would like to give 200KiB/s / per ip.

Is there any easy installable apache module? Or can I limit only download fibers? ... Download speed limit by IP, or connection...

Comment: Doable, yes.  Easy? No.  How much (which) of the infrastructure is owned/managed by you and how much (which) of the infrastructure is owned/managed by a 3rd party hosting group?

Comment: For instance [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) is not more granular than per VirtualHost (and not per directory/location, let alone per file-type) ...

Answer (score 0):

You have three approach at disposition, basically:

1. **[use lighttpd instead of Apache](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-set-throughput-connections-per-ip.html)**, as it has integrated bandwidth control and management
2. **use one of the various (non-official) Apache modules availables**, as [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/), [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/), [mod_limitipconn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html), ecc.
3. **use `tc` and/or `netfilter`** to create queues and mark packets based on source ports (which will be more or less unique, but remain at a manageagle ~64K entries)

I think that, for your use, you should really consider do use lighttpd (maybe even side-to-side to you Apache installation).

Other useful links: [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/191560/how-can-i-do-traffic-shaping-in-linux-by-ip) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second)